# Using coverage and codecov.io with both pytest unit tests and bespoke inline tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, code-coverage, coverage.py

The codebase for a Python project of mine contains lots of tests. These tests are broad and capacious enough that I would call them “robust”. I would like to know exactly how robust they are, so I have set up [the `coverage.py` tool](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.0.4/), and a [codecov.io account](https://codecov.io/gh/fish2000/CLU).

The project has two types of tests:

1. a suite of unit tests, which were written from the start to run with [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) – i.e. there are no legacy `unittest`-based tests, and `pytest` fixtures and hooks are heavily leveraged.
2. per-module inline test-function suites, written with [a simple bespoke test runner](https://github.com/fish2000/CLU/blob/2cbeaccc6662f642f87d961030b8202a1641d4d2/clu/testing/utils.py#L205-L579). These all look something like this:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys # …etc

# «module code»

def test():
    
    from clu.testing.utils import inline
    
    @inline.precheck
    def show_some_initial_values():
        """ Precheck function description """
        # «pre-check code»
    
    @inline
    def test_one():
        """ Test one’s description """
        # «test code»
    
    @inline
    def test_two():
        """ Test two’s description """
        # «test code»
    
    @inline.diagnostic
    def show_some_final_values():
        """ Diagnostic function description """
        # «post-run diagnostic code»
    
    return inline.test(100) # runs test functions 100 times;
                            # prechecks and diagnostics run once

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(test())
```

… and they output reports like so:

[image: inline test suite report screenshot]

… The inline tests can be run on a per-module basis, right from the editor. They can also all be run en masse via [a `nox` setup](https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/) that collects and runs [all modules that define inline tests](https://github.com/fish2000/CLU/blob/master/noxfile.py#L54-L61).

So now, regarding `coverage.py` and codecov.io – it was extremely easy to integrate the `pytest` suite with these tools. I made a few tweaks to an off-the-shelf `.coveragerc` file, installed the `pytest` codecov.io plugin, and that was that – those tests report their coverage to codecov.io just fine.

My question is, how do I integrate coverage reporting for the inline tests?

- Is there a simple way to configure `coverage.py` to “understand” these test functions, or do the inline tests need to report their results to the coverage tool(s)?
- Can one set something like this up within the `.coveragerc` file, or is it more involved?
- And, are there any other tools that I should consider, either additionally or instead of what I’m currently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage.py doesn't understand anything about tests.  All it does is tell you what parts of your code were run by some program.  Usually that program is a test runner, but coverage.py doesn't care.

If you run your tests now with `python mytestrunner.py`, change the command to `coverage run mytestrunner.py`, and you will get data.

Comment: Wow, that sounds almost too easy – do I have to put anything into the `.coveragerc` config file (or elsewhere) to “explain” anything about the test functions? Or can I count on reasonable heuristics because the functions all start with (or are just flat-out called) `test`?